# Повтор в SoundPool.play()

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с драконовскими ограничениями в `SoundPool` на использование ресурсов. Для того чтобы `soundPool.play()` проиграл нужный файл с аргументом loop более 0 (или -1) пришлось ужимать файл в 72 кб/с что не очень приемлемо в моем случае.

Есть альтернативы или способы решения?

Comment: в интернете говорят, что файл должен быть в формате 'wav', и размером < 1mb. Пробовали так? Еще говорят, что `SoundPool` сломался в Android 4.3

Comment: wav не пробовал, пробовал ogg, так как wav файлы в моем случае будут весить немеряно. В смысле сломался?

Comment: В смысле, что перестал работать как надо. Но я не уверен, что нагуглил, то и говорю. А вы попробуйте просто ради интереса с `wav`

Answer (score 1):

У себя для цикличного воспроизведению использую MediaPlayer.

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bg_music);
    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    if(dc.music())
        mPlayer.start();
}

 @Override protected void onDestroy() {
    mPlayer.release();
    super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mPlayer.pause();
}

@Override protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
    if(dc.music())
        mPlayer.start();
}

OnClickListener oclMusic = new OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    dc.music(!dc.music());
    main_btn_music.setImageResource(dc.music() ? R.drawable.music_on : R.drawable.music_off);
    if(dc.music()){
        mPlayer.start();
    } else{
        mPlayer.pause();
    }
}};
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, Rhino! Действительно, работать с MediaPlayer оказалось намного очевиднее и удобнее. Мой вариант, который заработал:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaPlayer drumLoop;
private boolean isDrumsAtTime;
private int currentDrumLoop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    currentDrumLoop = R.raw.medium_slowchina_nofill;

    isDrumsAtTime = false;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonPlayCurrentDrums:
            if (!isDrumsAtTime) {
                startLoop();
            } else {
                stopLoop();
            }
    }
}

private void setLoop(int drumLoopFile){
    drumLoop = MediaPlayer.create(this, drumLoopFile);
    drumLoop.setLooping(true);
}


public void startLoop(){
    setLoop(currentDrumLoop);
    drumLoop.start();
    isDrumsAtTime = true;
}

public void stopLoop() {
    drumLoop.stop();
    drumLoop.release();
    isDrumsAtTime = false;
}
```

}